# Can't figure out why code cannot apply to larger Range

Tags: google-apps-script

With a lot of help from S/O, I was able to get some code to work for a project where I am counting the number of duplicates in a sheet and then pushing an array element at the end that counts how many duplicates there are. See here: [Can't figure out how to add duplicate count to end of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681754/cant-figure-out-how-to-add-duplicate-count-to-end-of-array/72682045#72682045)

However, when I increase the range size to account for sheets with more columns (the current one has 13 columns), I keep getting the same error: **"Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 13 but the range has 14."**

What I'm gonna probably do is just map out the values from the new array's last column into the sheet's last column as long as the value is not "null". That's the only think I can think of for a temporary solution.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
function test () {

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("UTSheet");
let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
values.shift(); // remove the headers

let ids = values.map( row => row[0] ); // Reduces entire row to first element (SOR number), result is 1D array of SOR numbers
ids = [...new Set(ids)];  // create an array of unique ids (removes duplicates), result is 1D array

let count = ids.map( id => 0 ); // initialize count to 0
values.forEach( row => { let index = ids.indexOf(row[0]);
count[index]++;
}); //This foreach loop is where the number of SOR numbers are counted
  
    // now let put back into spreadsheet
    ids.forEach( (id,i) => { let j = values.findIndex( row => row[0] === id );
                             values[j][13] = count[i]; } );

sheet.getRange(15, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

}
```

```
123730  C       Gonzales, Cynthia¡  THR Hoffman     1245    1745    1630    3.25    Yes ED/KE
122857  C       Nunez Rocha, Alejandro(FTE5)    SOS NFS     1300    1800    2145    8.25        ED/KE
125116  C       Garcia, Miguel¡ LMD         1300    1800    1830    5       EB
122077  C       Zavala, Justin¡ QUE         1330    1830    2230    8.5     CG
124376  C       Gill, Maninderjit¡  IOC         1400    1900    2300    8.5 Yes CG
119588  C       Gonzales, Joe §§§¡  AFG NFS     1430    1930    2230    7.5     CG
122248  C       Hagos, Daniel   CBN         1430    1930    2330    8.5 Yes KE
124551  C       Pham, Joshua∞   YUI         1630    2130    1900    2       CG
125130  C       Malogan, Gil¡   ERT         1630    2130    230 9.5     CG
125130  C       Mendoza Suastes, Victor WER     Shift acceptance    1630    2130    230 9.5     CG
```

Comment: I don't get the error.  Perhaps you should supply and table of your data.

Comment: I think I'm having a hard time understanding how to paste the count values into the column I want. For example, in the sheet that works, when I change the code from "[3]" to another number I get the same error message:     ids.forEach( (id,i) => { let j = values.findIndex( row => row[0] === id );
                             values[j][3] = count[i]; } );

Comment: As @Cooper has commented, kindly share sample data _(e.g. Sample Sheet)_ so people in the community will be able to replicate your setup & further dissect your script. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Oops.. huge noob here bear with me! I just posted the table in the edited version

Comment: I'm wondering if each row is the same length.  Was the original values array 14 columns?

Comment: I have checked each index values of your **values** array variable and I can confirm that the last array value only contains _13_ [as seen here](https://imgur.com/a/IejQ6uy)

Comment: The test data I'm using has 13 columns, although the values within the columns can vary (the duplicates I'm counting are from values in the first column). Some cells may be blank, but even in filing them in with something, I get the same error

Comment: This has been my current workaround in case anyone runs into this: // Filter rows where Officer Count r[5] == "null";
let newarr = values.filter(filterlogic);
// Logger.log(newarr);
beatSheet.getRange(2, 4, newarr.length, newarr[0].length).setValues(newarr);

}


//Filter Variable

var filterlogic = function(item) {
  if(item[5] == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

*Issue found in your current script:*

> In the script after the comment *`// now let put back into spreadsheet`*, the first instance of the id `125130` has already been found thus, the next duplicate of `125130` id's row length will remain unchanged, causing the error ***"Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 13 but the range has 14."*** as other data row lengths are changed to 14 except for one in the `values` array.

Perhaps you can try this script below, which I think has a simpler implementation:

### Proposed Script

```
function test2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UTSheet");
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();
  let output = []; //Container of row data with unique IDs
  let colA = [...values.map(x => x[0])];

  values.forEach(row => {
    if (output.map(x => x[0]).includes(row[0])) //if an ID already exists in the output variable, it will be ignored
      return;
    row.push(colA.filter(x => x == row[0]).length) //adds the ID's total count (if it has duplicates Or 1 if none) at the end of each row of data of that current ID in the loop
    output.push(row); //put the first ID instance data with total count in the "output" variable
  });

  sheet.getRange(15, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

### Demonstration

[image]

> Execution without **exception error**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is quite helpful and I will be sure to study this. I really appreciate it!